# Which is a better option on mobiles.. sprites or individual image files for an app

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova

This is mainly a question for someone who has adequate experience with mobile development in both android and ios, and knows about mobile application optimizations and performance, so please refrain from answering generic solutions like "choose what you like or what suits your preference etc".

So, I am developing a mobile app for ios and android in phonegap, and it has graphics for almost all possible social medias like facebook, twitter, snapchat. My questions is whether I should maintain the icons/graphics for each media as individual files, or as a combined sprite image.

I understand on web sprites are the best options, but since these graphics are embedded in the app, it should not be a problem for the mobile app. Only thing I am concerned about is how the number of embedded images and icons in the app will affect the performance of the app.

I prefer to keep each social media icon in separate file because it is used at various places in the app with different styles and sizes, so using a sprite in that place would mean taking care of background size, image width all individually, whereas with the individual icons it is very straight forward. Also makes it easy to add/change medias to the app without modifying existing graphics.

So if someone can please tell me what effect will it have on keeping individual icons and graphics within the phonegap app instead of sprites and whether it is the better option or not!

Comment: I still use sprites in my current workflow even on the cordova app because I have a gulp setup to generate my sprites and the CSS for it. https://medium.com/front-end-wtf/simple-css-retina-sprite-with-sass-and-compass-5e667cdeec3f

Comment: Sprites that might have many images which may lead to width or height of more than 3000px. I have had issues with images loading on iOS with that size, sometimes it doesn't even load. If you can try using SVG as individual images as since they are just code, performance is not affected much apparently.

Comment: @giri thanks for that info, I didn't know that..

Answer (score -1):

i have worked with a android for over two years and i have realized that pngs are the best format to work with in android application and for JPEGs the best practise is to use a hyphen to name the JPEGs eg image_one.jpeg

Using png's will be the best format as they have never failed.I would gladly help if u need more assistance

Comment: This is not what I asked for.. please read the question carefully